# html element is loaded inside my html page but not displayed - hot to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a main **index.html** page with a graph made with d3.js:

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Training</title>
    <meta name="description">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/architecturetree/css/tree.css" />
    
</head>

<body>
  <div id="graph"> <!-- View the graph-->
    <h1><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Training</h1>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <div id="includedContent"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to add a stepper to the index.html page when I click on a tree node. So I add the following code portion in my **tree.js**:

```
$.ajax({url:'views/stepper.html',success:function(data){$("#includedContent").html(data)}})
```

which should add the .html file to show the stepper.

This file (**stepper.html**) is as follows:

```
<div class="step">
  </br></br></br>
    <md-card ng-init="step2.disabled = true; step3.disabled = true; selected = 0">
      <md-steppers  md-selected="selected" md-stretch-steppers="always">
        <md-step label="Lab1" md-complete="step1.completed"> 
          <md-content>
            <iframe id="iframe0" name="myIframe0" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
            <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 1; step1.completed=true; step2.disabled = false">NEXT</md-button>
          </md-content>
        </md-step>
        <md-step label="Lab2" md-complete="step2.completed" ng-disabled="step2.disabled">
          <md-content>
            <iframe id="iframe1" name="myIframe1" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 0">PREV</md-button>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 2; step2.completed=true; step3.disabled=false">NEXT</md-button>
          </md-content>
        </md-step>
        <md-step label="End" md-complete="step3.completed" ng-disabled="step3.disabled">
          <md-content>
            <h1>
            All done!
            </h1>
            <h5> </br> You have completed this training path. </br> You can go back through the labs or select another training.
            </h5>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 1">PREV</md-button>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="step2.disabled = true; step3.disabled = true; selected = 0">START</md-button>
          </md-content>
        </md-step>
      </md-steppers>
    </md-card>
  </div>
```

So, in this case the block with the stepper is loaded but is not shown. Only a white block appears. If I do "inspect element" from the browser the content of stepper.html is actually present, only that it is not shown. What could be the problem?

With `div ng-include = "views / stepper.html"` in the index.html the stepper appears but I need a function in javascript that is called only when you click on a node of the graph.

In the pic you can see the white box at the bottom as it appears.
[image]

Comment: Mixing jQuery and Angular seems like a bad idea in general.  Why aren't you using Angular functionality to load the new content?

Comment: how? I've been puzzling for days. Any solution that solves my problem is fine with me.

Comment: do you want a solution with ajax only? coz i don't know the ajax. but i have solution using  Bootstrap/css and javasctipt.

Comment: @OmkarKalantre, yes i'm fine with your solution too, thanks

Comment: ok i will post ans to this in few minutes.

Comment: First of all, your HTML is invalid. The `<div id="graph">` tag does not get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution...

**First:**

just keep your data which you want to add onclick in your

```
<div id="includedContent">
<!-- here your data to add onclick -->
</div>
```

**Second:**
and just add it css property display: none

```
#includedContent {
    display: none;
}
```

Note: don't use inline css method to set property display : none

**Third:**
set onclick function using java script

```
onclick="document.getElementById('includedContent').style.display='block'"
```

This code works onclick of your h1 tag "Tranning". you can keep it on anywhere.
That's it..
For more clearance checkout the code snippet attached below..
i have used only basic html, css, js so your graphs are not visible but you can see that are added also text part are visible..

Hope you will get the idea. Have a good day.

```css
#includedContent {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

    <title>Training</title>
    <meta name="description">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/architecturetree/css/tree.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="graph">
        <!-- View the graph-->
        <h1 onclick="document.getElementById('includedContent').style.display='block'"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Training</h1>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>

        <div id="includedContent">
            <div class="step">
                </br>
                </br>
                </br>
                <md-card ng-init="step2.disabled = true; step3.disabled = true; selected = 0">
                    <md-steppers md-selected="selected" md-stretch-steppers="always">
                        <md-step label="Lab1" md-complete="step1.completed">
                            <md-content>
                                <iframe id="iframe0" name="myIframe0" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
                                <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 1; step1.completed=true; step2.disabled = false">NEXT</md-button>
                            </md-content>
                        </md-step>
                        <md-step label="Lab2" md-complete="step2.completed" ng-disabled="step2.disabled">
                            <md-content>
                                <iframe id="iframe1" name="myIframe1" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
                                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 0">PREV</md-button>
                                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 2; step2.completed=true; step3.disabled=false">NEXT</md-button>
                            </md-content>
                        </md-step>
                        <md-step label="End" md-complete="step3.completed" ng-disabled="step3.disabled">
                            <md-content>
                                <h1>
                                    All done!
                                </h1>
                                <h5>
                                    </br> You have completed this training path. </br> You can go back through the labs or select another training.
                                </h5>
                                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 1">PREV</md-button>
                                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="step2.disabled = true; step3.disabled = true; selected = 0">START</md-button>
                            </md-content>
                        </md-step>
                    </md-steppers>
                </md-card>
            </div>
        </div>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this solution later!

Comment: it works, could you also tell me how to reload the content of the div in which the stepper is present? Because if I change the node that is clicked, the stepper does not start from scratch but always from the last step.